# Conflicting hard drive space reports, missing about 46gb of space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        36G   22G   12G  65% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.1M  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.8G   69M  3.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       917G  863G  7.7G 100% /store
tmpfs           769M  4.0K  769M   1% /run/user/1000
```

So this is the output from *df -h*, the thing I'm asking about is the free space I seem to be missing from /dev/sda1.  917 - 863 does not equal 7.7.  So the question is: how do I find out what's taking up that space, and how do I get it back?  There shouldn't be any system files on the drive (in case those could be hiding space used), it's used exclusively for storing media; pictures, videos, music, and the like.

To be honest, I have no idea why this would be happening and I don't really know the information needed to find out what it is so please tell me what you need.  I'm running a Debian 8 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ever-helpful [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ext4#Remove_reserved_blocks):

> By default 5% of a filesystem will be flagged as reserved for root user to avoid fragmentation.

You have a disk of 917 GB, 95% of it (*i.e.*, after subtracting the quota used to avoid fragmentation) is 871 GB, which corresponds exactly to the sum of free and unoccupied space that you see with the *df -h* command.

Since you are using the disk as a long term storage device, where the risks of fragmentation are smaller due to the presence, typically, of larger and less numerous files, you may, if you wish, reduce the disk quota reserved to counteract fragmentation, by means of the command:

```
  tune2fs -m 2.0 /dev/sda1
```

This reduces the quota to 2% of the total.